# Change discriminator value/discriminated type in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discriminator

I've represented a class hierarchy in Mongoose via two models and a discriminator key (simple example):

```
var options = {discriminatorKey: 'kind'};
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {type: String, index: true},
    // some other fields
}, options);

// some  schema methods

var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
var PowerUserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {type: String, index: true},
    // some other fields
    rank: {type: String}
}, options);
var PowerUser = User.discriminator('PowerUser', PowerUserSchema);
```

So far this works fine, however I ran into the situation, where I would like to "promote" a User to PowerUser. My initial idea was to set the "kind" property of a user and call save() on the instance, hoping that once the value is retrieved next time, the correct mongoose type will be returned:

```
var user = ... // retrieve user
user.kind = 'PowerUser';
user.save();
user = ... // retrieve user again
```

This doesn't appear to work, since the "kind" value is not saved to the instance. I came across [this](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3839) suggestion, which unfortunately did not update the discriminator value either.

My question now is: Am I even on the right track? Is updating the discriminator value even allowed for a situation like this, or should I better structure my data in a different way (e.g. use a single schema for both, with a "type" entry specifying what each instance is; this would have the effect that for the demotion case, no information is lost.)

Additionally, pro(de)moting a user should not break all the instances in my database where (Power)Users are referenced.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you add roles array to each user and then add and remove them as you like?

Comment: So you "could" do that, but simply modifying the discriminator value in the data doesn't sound very OOP to me. Presumably `PowerUser` has different properties and possibly "validation rules" or at least some "required" data that distinguishes. Therefore it's probably more "correct" to instead "cast" the object to as a `PowerUser` and then save it.

Comment: And *"unfortunately did not update"* because you did not **read** the issue referenced. If you look at the post you will see `{discriminatorKey: 'kind'}` was passed to the Schema options. This means that the "default" value for this key is being overridden. Which is why the later suggestion is to set the `.kind` property. By "default" the property for the discriminator key is named `__t`. Therefore `user.__t = "PowerUser"`. But like I said, hacky!

Comment: So, casting a "User" to "PowerUser" in JavaScript, and saving it back to the db is valid for mongoose/mongodb? I'd prefer a solution like this, since, as you said, it is more OOP.
Will this approach break existing references to the User instance though?

Comment: The referenced method does not work for me either. I feel this is a mongoose bug.

Answer (score 2):

In the end I got this to work by doing:

```
var user = ... // retrieve user
var powerUser = PowerUser.hydrate(user.toObject());
powerUser.kind = 'PowerUser';
powerUser.save();
powerUser = ... // retrieve user again
```

On a side note, demoting a PowerUser back to User does not appear to be working that way.

Comment: It may not work as you expected. If `user` and `powerUser` has their own properties, then after conversion, the old property of `user` is still set in the new `powerUser`. It must be a bug.

Comment: Looks like issue why it is not working is when you hydrate object it won't let mongodb know it has changed. So you needed to add powerUser.markModified('kind')

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using **findOneAndUpdate** on the Model

```
 User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: _user._id}, {$set: {kind: "PowerUser"}, {new: true}, function (err, doc) {
        should.not.exist(err);
        should.exist(doc.kind);
        doc.kind.should.equal('PowerUser');

        done();
      });
```

you could use a static method like this in case you also need to remove properties already set. the value new: true is to get the new modified file and strict: false so you can unset values that dont already exist on UserSchema

```
changes = {kind: "PowerUser"}

UserSchema.statics.switchKind = function (id, changes, callBack) {
  const unset = {
    rank: undefined,
    someOtherField: undefined
  };
  return this.findOneAndUpdate({_id: id}, {$set: changes, $unset: unset}, {new: true, strict: false}, callBack);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Mongoose 6, you can modify the value of the discriminator key by using the [`overwriteDiscriminatorKey option`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html#updating-the-discriminator-key):

For some reason it wasn't validating correctly for me with any of the "update" methods (e.g. `findByIdAndUpdate`) ([bug report](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/12989)), so I had to do a replace, which means you need to provide the whole document:

```
const user = ... // retrieve user
const newUser = {
    ...user.toObject(), ...{ kind: 'PowerUser', name: 'New Name' }
};
User.replaceOne({ _id: user._id }, newUser, {
    overwriteDiscriminatorKey: true,
    runValidators: true
});
```

This will validate it against the `PowerUser` schema to make sure your document is valid.